# C# incorrect regex

Tags: c#, regex, .net-2.0

I want to search through all the files with this name: Resources.Designer.pas, Settings.Designer.pas.

My line of code is:

```
if (myString.Equals("*.Designer.pas"))
```

but it doesn't enter in the if block. Why?

Comment: That's not a regex. `String.Equals` is checking for the exact value. If you want to use regex and the `*` wildcard, check the [`IsMatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4.aspx) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (myString.EndsWith(".Designer.pas"))
```

Answer (score 2):

In regular expressions, the `.` is a special character that means 'match any character'. If you want to explicitly match a period, you will have to escape it. This should work:

```
string pattern = @".*\.Designer\.pas";
if (Regex.IsMatch(myString, pattern))
```

For more information, please take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966.aspx) msdn article. The above will however match anything of the form `foo.Designer.pas.bar`, where `foo` and `bar` represent any string. If you would like to explicitly match any files ending with `.Designer.pas`, you should use something like this:

```
string pattern = @".*\.Designer\.pas$";
if (Regex.IsMatch(myString, pattern))
```

The `$` will instruct the regex engine to match that substring and make sure it is the last part of the string.

Comment: I have made changes to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could also use:

```
if (myString.EndsWith(".Designer.pas", 
                      StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
Regex.IsMatch(str, "\.Designer\.pas$")
```

to ensure a given string ends with ".Designer.pas".

Answer (score 0):

because you refer to the literal string "*.Designer.pas". This probably doesn't exist. I suggest you try searching for ".Designer.pas" That way you will get the results you are looking for..

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a list of files on the filesystem that match a certain pattern, you can use `Directory.GetFiles`:

```
foreach(string f in Directory.GetFiles("C:\\YourPath", "*.Designer.pas"))
{
    ...
}
```

You can also use `.` instead of `C:\\YourPath` to use the current directory.